# Text message contacts on Galaxy S4

Tags: sms

When I create a new text message and enter into my contacts, it loads my gmail contacts, as opposed to just my contacts that have phone numbers which is what I really want.  I've played around in the settings menus, but nothing I do seems to work.  Any ideas?